# Is it possible for reviewers to mistakenly reject a quality paper?

Tags: research-process, peer-review, reference-request, rejection

If I am not wrong, turbo codes was submitted to the ICC conference and rejected but accepted later on.

I want to know if there are other similar works (strong works) that were rejected at first but then accepted and considered revolutionary.

Comment: I have no doubt that this happens all the time.

Comment: This happens extremely often. The trick is not getting this  confused with the converse (my paper gets rejected => it's awesome)

Comment: *cough* Copernicus/Galileo *cough*

Comment: Not a journal publication, but Galois was rejected by Polytechnique twice.

Comment: Also note that there's a difference between _good research_ and a _good paper_. It's definitely possible to do groundbreaking research, but then have it rejected due to poorly communicating what you actually did in your write up. If the reviewers can't understand what you did they're not going to recommend the paper be accepted.

Comment: Just as an indication of _how_ often that happens, I read your question title and simply laughed out loud.

Comment: Yes. Especially if the reviewer writes "I don't find the problem interesting" just because he's been stuck to his XYZ method and know that and nothing else.

Comment: Hah. Forget about rejected papers. What about a rejected life? Read the amazing story of the life of [Doctor Ignaz Semmelweis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignaz_Semmelweis). He thought hand washing was a good idea. His colleagues disagreed, and he was eventually committed to an insane asylum. I'm not making this up.

Comment: In top-tier journals, it can be enough for 1 reviewer to reject the paper for the paper to get rejected. Then consider the fact that many reviewers often do not understand the papers they review in depth. Finally, some reviewers may understand the paper but reject it due to a personal agenda (they may or may not try to hide this). So it is not surprising that rejection of great papers happens all the time.

Comment: There was also the case of Alfred Wegener and the continental drift. Rejection of a good paper is not necessarily bad, as the next version may be even better and have even more influence. On the other hand, what about the clutter of bad papers that get accepted.

Comment: For examples in mathematics, you can have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13896/what-are-some-famous-rejections-of-correct-mathematics/13983#13983.

Comment: Of course this never happens: reviewers have special super-powers, so they are always correct!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Higgs**'s 1964 paper on the Higgs mechanism was rejected by *Physics Letters* (where his preliminary paper on the subject was published).

He was told that it was not suitable for rapid publication and that he should send it to another journal. However, he [reportedly](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/the-heart-of-the-matter-54071.html) heard that the paper had been rejected because the editors felt that "it was of no obvious relevance to physics."

Apparently, Higgs acknowledged that the paper "had been short on sales talk," and after adding a couple of paragraphs it was accepted by *Physical Review Letters*.

Here is an [early example](http://sss.sagepub.com/content/23/2/342.abstract) of manuscript rejection, from 1842: **Mayer** came up with the theory of conservation of energy, and wrote an article explaining his idea that "energy is neither created nor destroyed." It was rejected by the leading physics journal of the time, ended up in an obscure chemistry journal, and was mostly ignored by physicists. When the physicists of the time rallied around Joule, who described conservation of energy later in the 1840s, Mayer suffered a mental breakdown. Towards the end of his life, he was finally given credit as a father of thermodynamics.

*Nature* declined to accept **Krebs**'s paper on the "Krebs cycle" in 1937. The work later won a Nobel Prize. The [letter from the editor](http://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/28819/title/Nature-rejects-Krebs-s-paper--1937/) regretfully informs Mr. Krebs that the editor already has "sufficient letters" for the next 7-8 weeks.

The seminal paper on quantum cryptography, **Wiesner**'s “Conjugate Coding,” was [rejected](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0604072.pdf) by the *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory*. (A surviving copy of the original typewritten manuscript says "Submitted to IEEE, Information Theory" on it.) It was published about a decade later.

In the same subfield, the original manuscript by **Bennet, Brassard and Breidbart** that introduced quantum key-recycle scheme (QKRS) was [rejected](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0604072.pdf) several times by major CS conferences including STOC, and was never successfully published.

**Ernst**'s work on nuclear magnetic resonance spectroscopy, which won the 1991 Nobel Prize in Chemistry, was [rejected](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/chemistry/laureates/1991/ernst-bio.html) not once, but twice, by the *Journal of Chemical Physics*.

**Binning** and **Rohrer**'s report on their first experiments in scanning tunneling microscopy, which earned them a Nobel Prize in Physics in 1986, was initially [rejected](http://scx.sagepub.com/content/16/3/304.short) on the grounds that it was "not interesting enough."

These are just a few examples. Many more have been compiled in various publications:

- Here are some more [Nobel-prize-winning](http://www.gwern.net/docs/dnb/2008-gonzalezalvarez.pdf) papers that were rejected at first.
- Here is a [compilation of classic economics papers](http://cahnrs-cms.wsu.edu/ses/people/chouinard/Documents/GansAndShepard.pdf) rejected the first time around.
- And here are some [famous papers in the field of medicine](http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=380984) that were rejected the first time around.
- [This paper lists influential rejected papers](http://scx.sagepub.com/content/16/3/304.short), of which several earned their authors Nobel prizes and several became the most cited papers in their respective journals.
- And here are some more [reports of Nobel laureates](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11192-008-2141-5) who encountered resistance from reviewers and editors to their award-winning work.
- And, [yet another list](http://sss.sagepub.com/content/23/2/342.abstract).

Comment: One more, Lamport's original Paxos paper was rejected several times. See [his history](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/pubs.html#lamport-paxos). Paxos and its derivatives are now at the core of almost all large-scale web-sites (Google, Microsoft, Amazon, ...).

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff that's a great read - I think you should add it as an answer to http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17873/article-that-shows-the-complete-publication-history-of-acceptances-and-rejection

Comment: Well timed since Lamport just got the Turing award.

Comment: @ff524: [done](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18563/13468).

Comment: The original Google paper (by Page and Brin) on "PageRank" was rejected by SIGIR. However, this is not to say it should have been accepted. Even if a paper goes on to have huge impact, it does not mean that the paper at the time it was submitted, in the form it was submitted, definitively should have been published.

Answer (score 9):

Originally posted on [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17873/article-that-shows-the-complete-publication-history-of-acceptances-and-rejection/25953#25953), but it may be more useful in helping to answer this one. [This article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/asi.20556/abstract) by Juan Miguel Campanario and Erika Acedo investigates the question of paper rejection:

> Rejecting highly cited papers: The views of scientists who encounter resistance to their discoveries from other scientists

**Abstract:**

> We studied the views of scientists who experience resistance to their
>   new ideas by surveying a sample of 815 scientists who are authors of
>   highly cited articles. The 132 responses (16.2%) received indicated
>   that only 47 scientists (35.6%) had no problems with referees,
>   editors, or other scientists. The most common causes of difficulty
>   were rejection of the manuscript, and scepticism, ignorance, and
>   incomprehension. The most common arguments given by referees against
>   papers were that the findings were an insufficient advance to warrant
>   publication, lacked practical impact, were based on a wrong
>   hypothesis, or were based on a wrong concept. The strategies authors
>   used to overcome resistance included obtaining help from someone to
>   publish problematic papers, making changes in the text, and simple
>   persistence. Despite difficulties, however, some respondents
>   acknowledged the positive effect of peer review.

It is published in the *Journal of the American Society for Information Science and Technology*.

Andrew Hayes writes about the subject, linking the above article, as well as this [second article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-4571%28199604%2947:4%3C302::AID-ASI6%3E3.0.CO;2-0/abstract) also by Juan Miguel Campanario, at [his blog](http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/rejected-keep-at-it).

**Full citations, for posterity's sake:**

Campanario, J. M. and Acedo, E. (2007), Rejecting highly cited papers: The views of scientists who encounter resistance to their discoveries from other scientists. J. Am. Soc. Inf. Sci., 58: 734–743. doi: 10.1002/asi.20556

Campanario, J. M. (1996), Have referees rejected some of the most-cited articles of all times?. J. Am. Soc. Inf. Sci., 47: 302–310. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1097-4571(199604)47:4<302::AID-ASI6>3.0.CO;2-0

Comment: Is it wrong that I felt disappointed that this story didn't end with "fittingly, the paper was rejected twice"?

Answer (score 3):

Dan Shechtman's paper in which he announced the discovery of quasicrystals was rejected for being "not interesting". It was accepted after few years in a different journal.

He won the Nobel Prize in 2011 for this discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the seminal papers that have proven of exceptional importance to science were rejected. Some of them over 13 times:
https://majesticforest.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/papers-that-triumphed-over-their-rejections/